# Laravel Call to undefined method App\\Models\\User::attempt()

Tags: laravel

Greetings I have Laravel project for APIs, I have register route and I have login route
when I use register route it working fine and storing the data in the database successfully, in the login function I am using User::attempt() function, when I try to use the login route it returns this error `Call to undefined method App\\Models\\User::attempt()`

the User model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username',
        'password',
        'access_token'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```

the login function

```
public function handleLogin(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['username' => 'required|string|max:100|min:3', 'password' => 'required|string|max:100|min:8']);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $errors = $validator->errors();
        return response()->json($errors);
    }

    $username = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;

    $is_user = User::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password]);

    if (!$is_user) {
        $error = 'Incorrect credentials';
        return response()->json($error);
    }

    $user = User::where('username', '=', $username);

    $new_access_token = Str::random(64);

    $user->update(['access_token' => $new_access_token]);

    return response()->json($new_access_token);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```php
$is_user = User::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])
```

Should be:

```php
$is_user = Auth::attempt(['username' => $username, 'password' => $password])
```

[Relevant docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticating-users)

Comment: `\Auth::attempt()` in particular.